# Can SwiftUI still able to redraw efficiently, since it doesn't require the model to conform protocol Equatable?

Tags: ios, swiftui

Based on https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/working-with-identifiable-items-in-swiftui

In SwiftUI, I can understand why `@ObservedObject` model, need to conform protocol `Identifiable`

It needs to understand, whether a model is being added/removed from current collection, so that it can perform correct UI updates.

But, **2 models with the same identifier, can have different content.**

Why doesn't SwiftUI, require the model to conform to the protocol `Equatable`?

I guess, SwiftUI will redraw a view, when the associated previous model, and  the associated current model, are having different identifiers.

I was wondering, how can SwiftUI decide whether to redraw or not, when the associated previous/current model, are having the same identifier, but the equality of their content is unknown.

If it chooses to redraw each time, isn't that is highly inefficient?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how `Equatable` would help.  SwiftUI knows the observed object has changed because a change was published (either explicitly with an `objectWillChange.send()` call or implicitly when an @Published property is changed).  So, SwiftUI will go about redrawing the view.  The view code will access certain variables in the model.  If none of those values have actually changed, then the new View and the previous one will be the same, and SwiftUI will skip the change.

Comment: Suppose SwiftUI need to draw from an Array of model. If the model doesn't conform `Equatable`, how does SwiftUI know, which model has changed, and which doesn't? I suppose SwiftUI only want to redraw for the model which has changes, and leave unchanged model as it is.

Comment: SwiftUI just recreates the view with the values that are specified in the code.  The model could have 10,000 properties, but the drawing code may only use 1 of those.  The view will be recreated using the current value, and if that didn't change the View, then the update will be skipped.  The key for efficiency is to only publish the changes your view cares about.